# How to hook the template rendering

Tags: angularjs

My site's theme uses custom checkboxes and other items that I need to style.  It uses `$(".styled, input:radio, input:checkbox, .dataTables_length select").uniform();` to do so.

I'm wondering if instead of creating a bunch of directives if I can just tap into the template rendering and execute this method on the template node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just a `uniform` directive, which then you apply to whatever needed? There are surely things (like the `.styled` ones) which do not come from a template directly.

Comment: I'd like to avoid having to use any directives at all.  If it's just natively supported the developer writing html doesn't have to do anything different to make it happen.